# CSS: nth-of-child and nth-of-type not working in my markup structure

Tags: html, css

I have tried both nth-of-child and nth-of-type a few times and read documentation on w3schools, css-tricks and mdn but can't figure this out.
It has worked for me in the past but now either nothing happens or all the spans get the css rule applied to them.

I'm just trying to add extra bottom padding to the first, second and eighth  with this following markup (repeated 8 times and all lis enclosed in parent ul:

```
<li class="campaign-links__list-item">
  <a class="campaign-links__link " href="/feast-on-london-under-25" id="104014" data-analytics="Category|£25 and Under|offpage">
      <img class="campaign-links__image opt-new--campaign-image" src="//img.static-bookatable.com/images/batweb/bat/sub-themes/feast-on-london/feast-on-london-under-25/hero.jpg?width=451&amp;height=150&amp;quality=80&amp;mode=crop" alt="£25 and Under" width="94" height="94">
      <span class="campaign-links__text opt-new--campaign-text" style="padding-bottom: 29px;">£25 and Under</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

This is the CSS I've tried:

```
.opt-new--campaign-text:nth-of-child(1), .opt-new--campaign-text:nth-of-child(2), .opt-new--campaign-text:nth-of-child(8) {
        padding-bottom: 29px;
    }

    .opt-new--campaign-text:nth-of-type(1), .opt-new--campaign-text:nth-of-type(2), .opt-new--campaign-text:nth-of-type(8)  {
        padding-bottom: 29px;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: it is only `:nth-child`, not `nth-of-child`

Comment: "*[..] padding to the first, second and eighth*"  -- Of what? first or second of what? `li` ? Why not just `li:nth-child(n);`?

Comment: Your `<img>` and `<span>` doesn't have any children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as nth-of-child, use `nth-child`. However you are selecting for the `opt-new--campaign-text` class which is a span. This span is the first child of type span, and second child of an `a` element.

What you're probably looking for is:

```
.campaign-links__list-item:nth-child(1) .opt-new--campaign-text {
    padding-bottom: 29px;
}
```

and so on. This selects the first (in this case `li`) child of the `ul` element, finds the `.opt-new--campaign-text` descendant, and adds padding to it.

Comment: Thanks very much, I thought this definitely would work, but another developer has put in this highly targeted css for list items: .campaign-links__list[data-count='8'] .campaign-links__list-item so my nth-child code doesn't seem to be coming through. Any ideas of how to override this? (I've already tried using !important)

Comment: Well you could simply match the specificity: 
`.campaign-links__list[data-count='8'] .campaign-links__list-item:nth-child(1) .opt-new--campaign-text {`

Comment: thanks actually I was doing something else wrong which fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're repeating the `li.campaign-links__list-item` block here? `nth-child` looks at child elements of the parent element, but `.opt-new--campaign-text` isn't repeated within it's immediate parent.

Something like this should work:

```
.campaign-links__list-item:nth-child(1) .opt-new--campaign-text, .campaign-links__list-item:nth-child(2) .opt-new--campaign-text, etc...
```

Comment: thanks for your help gwcodes, I upvoted your answer, but can only accept one person, so did that for Dan below.

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)